# req.body Undefined When testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I am unit testing my express app using Mocha and Chai

When in the test file, I want to use `req.body` to parse the object to only get undefined in the testing results.

I have body parser already required in the server `(app.js)`

What is I am missing I do get the response. This is calling a route that return a object `res.json(response)`

```
//Testing File

let chai = require('chai');
let expect  = require('chai').expect;
let request = require('request');
let app = require('../app');
let should = chai.should();


describe('/GET wallet', () => {
  it('object should have these properties', (done) => {
    request('http://localhost:3000/theFunction' ,function(error,res,req) {

      expect(res.body).to.have.property('name')


      done();
        });
  });
});
```

Comment: You seem to be confused about how the `request()` library works.  The third argument to the callback IS the body part of the response.  Just use that third argument directly.  This code has nothing to do with body parser.  That would be in the server and is for servers to parse POST or PUT requests which this is not.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are making a get request.

```
const options = 
{
 uri: 'http://localhost:3000/theFunction',
 method: 'POST',
 json: { "name": stackoverflow" } // json data you want to send. this will be populated as req.body
};

request(options, function (error, res, body) {
   expect(res.body).to.have.property('name')
   done();
});
```

Comment: Yeah because the route I am trying to test is a get request, and it returns a object with 4 properties. I am trying to test to see if the object maintains those 4 properties. That is why I do not understand you code above where you are entering your own json. Shouldnt you test the return?